# Hide or show editText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an editText(hidden by default) and a button. I want to show the editText on click of the button and hide when the button again is pressed. Also the editText should hide if the editText box loses focus.
How can this be done?
Thank you for the help in advanced.

Comment: show your initial code

Comment: Use editText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: Show what you had tried ?

Comment: Without xml and initial code its not possible to help you SO.Its also not recommended that without trying anything you ask for help.First post your effort what you have tried so far.Then only ask for help.Without trying anything asking for help does not help you in your career.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use like this   And the main concept here is  **editText.setVisibility(View.GONE);**

You have to add your animation file int res/anim/filename.xml suppose if you are not having means you have to create anim folder inside the res folder in your project..

slide_left_in.xml to inside...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
     android:fillAfter="true">

<translate
    android:fromXDelta="100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0%p"
    android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

left out animation you have to create separate files for all animation slide_right_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
android:fillAfter="true">

<translate
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toXDelta="-100%p"
    android:duration="350" />

</set>
```

you can use this animations in your activity like below.

```
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    final Animation slide_left_in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
            getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_left_in);
    final Animation slide_right_out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
            getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_right_out);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (editText.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                editText.startAnimation(slide_right_out);
                editText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                editText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                editText.startAnimation(slide_left_in);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to add the animation as well? I mean I want to get a sliding editText from right to left. Please help me with the same.

Comment: yeah sure i will edit my answer soon..

Comment: I edited my answer dude check out this answer

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make your `EditText` visiblity gone by `android:visibility="gone"` using this code in your `Layout.xml`

```
  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:visibility="gone" >
```

Then in your `Button` click event you need to use following code:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) { 
         if (myEditText.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
             // showing the EditText
             myEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             myEditText..requestFocus(); //Request Focus on EditText
         } else{
            myEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }
});
```

***EDIT***

***For Animation*** you can use [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/), [this](https://github.com/hascode/android-animation-sample), [this](https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki/Animations) and [this](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations)

Comment: Can you tell me how to add the animation as well? I mean I want to get a sliding editText from right to left. Please help me with the same.

Comment: what kind of animation ?

Comment: I've edited the comment. want to add animation where the editText slides from right to left and exits the same way.

Comment: yes follow the code and customize according to your need.